# Compare SQL database schema when its exported to file

Tags: mysql, compare, local

I have 2 databases live and development, i want to compare them, but phpMyAdmin dont have this functionality.

Now i could use some programs like phpStorm, mySQLToad etc. but they do connection from local computer to remote server and in my server options i dont want to allow any connections except local host.

Is there any tools that can compare database structures from files e.g. i export database with phpMyAdmin to file db1.sql and db2.sql can i compare their structure?

Comment: I am on windows platform i dont have diff here. I however have program like WinMerge to compare files. However want something more than text comparison.

Comment: There are lots of alternatives.  It sounds like you probably want SQL-Compare - an excellent product: http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-tools/

Comment: I must admit exporting structure only in phpMyAdmin from both tables and using WinMerge is really easy, i just want something more advanced in case there's a lot of changes.

Answer (score 0):

you could try redgate sqlcomprare.
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

theres one for oracle too:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/

Comment: dont know if it support mysql.

Comment: page reads: •Supports Oracle 9i, 10g, 11g and Amazon RDS for Oracle.

Comment: heres the one for mysql.
http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-tools/?gclid=CKqN15GXxbICFeeDQgodRWYA9g